# createMediaElementSource() performance

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm using the `Web Audio API` to analyse music played from an HTML `<audio>` tag using `createMediaElementSource()`. When I now call `play()/pause()` on the audio element from js I get a delay of up to a couple of seconds before anything happens. Also, when continuing to play after pausing, the audio stutters for a few secs.

My setup is as simple as it gets: A hidden `<audio>` created using JavaScript, an `AnalyserNode` attached to it, the analyser connected to the context's destination and then calling `play` on the Audio-Element. Before someone says it, no it's not the Analyser, it does the same thing without it.

I also noticed a bit of clipping (maybe due to stuttering?) when playing some mp3 files.

I'm using Apache Cordova, but on the *Windows 10 UWP* platform, so performance in general shouldn't be the problem.

Any idea why or how to circumnavigate that issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always good if you can include a bit of code and a description of what you've tried so far, so that we can see where you might be going wrong and point you in the right direction. In my answer below I just made an assumption about your setup that might be wrong, so the more you include the better the answers will be.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the preload attribute, like so;

```
<audio preload="auto">...</audio>
```

on your audio element to allow it to prebuffer a little.

Comment: Hm, that changed absolutely nothing... I also updated the question, I know that it was very spare at first, sorry for that.

Comment: Does it work the same loaded as a web page (rather than in Cordova)?